# "getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL" not redirecting

Tags: java, applet

I've integrated the following code in my main code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class AppletExample extends Applet {

    public void init() {

       try {
             getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("http://www.google.com"), "_blank");
       }
       catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
       }
    }

    public void paint( Graphics g ) {

       g.drawString("Go Google", 0,100);
    }

}
```

The idea is that `getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("http://www.google.com"), "_blank");` would redirect the user in applet, but it just won't do it. I've tried different stuff besides _blank, such as _self

What to do? Why doesn't it redirect?

Comment: try doing this in start() method.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple cases why this can happen:

First, to quote from the `AppletContext`-JavaDoc:

> [**void showDocument(URL url)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL%29)
>
> Requests that the browser or applet viewer show the Web page indicated
>   by the url argument. The browser or applet viewer determines which
>   window or frame to display the Web page. **This method may be ignored
>   by applet contexts that are not browsers.**

and to quote from your particular method-call (which is the overloaded version):

> [**void showDocument(URL url, String target)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29)
>
> [...] An applet viewer or browser is *free to ignore `showDocument`.*

So, if you're not viewing the Applet in a browser or the browser does decide to ignore your call, you can't do anything about it.

---

Also, it seems that it depends on the VM-implementation if this is even supported in the first place. See this [older post from an Apple Mailing-List](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2001/Apr/msg00658.html).

Last but not least, when I tried it myself, it worked, but the request was blocked by the PopUp-Blocker (and had to be manually granted). I used:

- Mozilla Firefox 12.0
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20), 64Bit
- All on Linux